# ENV Encryption not working in the Laravel version 9.32

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have upgraded the Laravel version to 9.32 and followed the below steps to encrypt the ENV file but it's not working. The env decryption on run time not working. It shows a database connection issue.

run php artisan env:encrypt --force --key=base64:{key from env file APP_KEY }
It will provide the Key and other information.
apply the same key in the config/app.php 'key' => '{key used in encryption}',
Run the php artisan config: clear command to clear config.

I have tried to use the same key in the ENV and config/app.php file. It generate the .env.encrypted file but when I try to connect to mysql database, it is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your problem. When encrypting the `.env` file, you will need to decrypt it again, to make the `.env` available for your environment. The decryption needs to happen before you cache or optimize your application's settings.

Comment: How to decrypt it? It's a Laravel feature in version 9.32

Comment: @Atui , decryption is done with `php artisan env:decrypt --key={the key outputted from the encryption process}`

Comment: I have done it but when I run the website, it's not working.  The env decryption not working run time. It does not get the database setting from the env file.

Comment: How do you verify that the decryption doesn't work? Doesn't the `.env` file get generated when you decrypt or?

Comment: I use the env. encrypted file and I think it should decrypt on run time when I open the website on the browser.

Comment: That's not how it works. And you've already confirmed that by the fact that it doesn't work. You need to, as initially stated, decrypt the encrypted file after deployment.